# Here's a bum triage audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

[string input parameter for c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183887/string-input-parameter-for-c-program)

The question posed is, literally, 'how can I write my code?' tacked onto a short wall. This is not what we call a good question.

The fact that it is written in English and one can see what the OP's problem is does not make it a good question.

Comment: The up-votes are probably being given because the question is somewhat well formatted (although not a reason to upvote either) and has a large size, I've seen it happen a lot.

Comment: In your opinion, would the question be a better one if the last sentence of the question read "How do I fix my error," rather than "can anybody help me to write the 3 functions of my requirement?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It might be an insignificantly better post imho, but a worse review-audit.

Comment: It would qualify for improvement rather than closure.

Comment: The question should be re asked to fit the awesome answer.

Comment: That's a serious meta-effect. (At least) +5 to -2 in less than a day...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was audit-blocked due to this. Care to unblock me?